# jquery datepicker onselect not firing

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-validate

I have 2 input boxes for inputing start date and end date.I need to verify that the start date is earlier than the end date.I have the following code to verify that but the code doesn't seem to be firing when I attach to the onselect event of the datepicker control.Can someone please tell what I'm doing wrong?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $(".date").datepicker({
           onSelect:function(dateText,inst){

           var startDate=new Date($("#_createDateFromInput").val());
           var endDate=new Date($("#_createDateToInput").val());
           if(startDate!=""&&endDate!="")
            {
                if(startDate>endDate)
                {
                    alert("End date cannot be earlier than start date");
                }
             }

          }

       });});
   </script>
```

thanks!!

The markup for the above is(this is in asp.net):

```
<label>Date From</label> 
<input class="date" runat="server"  id="_createDateFromInput" />
<label id="to">To</label>
<input class="date" runat="server"  id="_createDateToInput"  />
```

El Ronnoco had I believe has latched onto something...I notice when I remove the runat="server" tag I am able to fire the even...however now I am faced with another
issue to retrieve the value during post back(i.e when user finally submits)..any one have an idea?

Comment: What is the markup for your elements `_createDateFromInput` and `_createDateToInput`. I imagine that your startDate and endDate vars are not being populated correctly.

Comment: <label>Date From</label> 
                             <input class="date" runat="server"  id="_createDateFromInput" />
                             <label id="to">To</label>
                             <input class="date" runat="server"  id="_createDateToInput"  />

Comment: El Ronnoco u were right I have added what I found to my query,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to achieve this is to prevent that the user can select an earlier date for the endDate.

This can be simply done by using the minDate option of Datepicker plugin

```
$("#startDate").datepicker({
    onSelect:function(dateText,inst){
        $( "#endDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(dateText) );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code, from the jQuery UI example page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-search

Basically it takes 2 inputs, makes them datepickers then onselect limits both the mindate and max date. It's a very clever piece of code.

```
$(function() {
    var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for all your input.I used a lot of what you had written down.I was able to make that work for some reason having the attribute `runat="server"` causes all kinds of problems for jquery.I had to remove the tag and access it using the request object that is inherent in the page.For those interested in the syntax:

```
request.form["startDate"].tostring();
```

where startdate is the attribute name value for that field.

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it